# AWS Sagemaker Custom Widget Installation Jupyter Notebook or Lab

Tags: amazon-web-services, widget, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to install our custom Jupyter widget on AWS Sagemaker. I assume that I need to use Lifecycle configuration. However, I first tried to install on the Classic Jupyter notebook terminal

```
$ pip install clustergrammer2
$  jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix clustergrammer2
>> clustergrammer2 backend version 0.17.0
Enabling notebook extension clustergrammer2/extension...
      - Validating: OK
```

However, when I re-start the notebook kernel and do a hard refresh on the browser I get the following error in the browser console

```
require.js?v=951f856e81496aaeec2e71a1c2c0d51f:168 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Script error for "clustergrammer2"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js?v=951f856e81496aaeec2e71a1c2c0d51f:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js?v=951f856e81496aaeec2e71a1c2c0d51f:1735)
```

Next, I tried the following Lifecycle configuration

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# OVERVIEW
# This script installs a single pip package in a single SageMaker conda environments.

sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
# PARAMETERS
ENVIRONMENT=python3
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"
pip install scipy scikit-learn ipywidgets matplotlib statsmodels clustergrammer2
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix clustergrammer2
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
EOF
```

but the widget is not working and I'm seeing an error

```
Could not instantiate widget
```

in the JavaScript console.

The issue has also been raised on GitHub https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2958

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the "install" command before running the "enable" command. Once I did this our custom Jupyter widget Clustergrammer2 worked in the Classic notebook (found this answer here https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1146#issuecomment-405711469).

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# OVERVIEW
# This script installs a single pip package in a single SageMaker conda environments.

sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
# PARAMETERS
ENVIRONMENT=python3
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"

pip install scipy scikit-learn ipywidgets matplotlib statsmodels==0.11.1 clustergrammer2
jupyter nbextension install --user --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension install --user --py clustergrammer2
jupyter nbextension enable --user --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension enable --user --py clustergrammer2

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
EOF
```

I will raise a question about how to get the widget installed in Jupyter Lab.